# Printing binary digits of a number

Tags: java, loops

Need to write a java program from pseudo code, I've got a bit of code written, its not working and I'm not sure if i've done it right or not as I simply tried to follow the pseudo code -

- Read i
- While i > 0
- Print the remainder i % 2
- Set i to i / 2

  ```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class InputLoop
  {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
          int i = 0;
          Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
          System.out.println("Enter an integer");
          while (!scan.hasNextInt()) // while non-integers are present
          {
              scan.next();
              System.out.println ("Bad input. Enter an integer.");
          }
          while (i>0) // while greater than 0
          {
              int input = scan.nextInt();
              System.out.println (i%2);
              i = (i/2);
          }

      }
  }
  ```

Comment: don't use division for this. use a bitwise shift, `>>` operator.

Comment: `i` always stays at 0. You aren't assigning anything to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frankly speaking, you `didn't`(Ah missed it earlier) exactly followed the pseudo-code. The pseudo code tells you to `read i`, whereas you are reading `input`. That's one problem.

Second problem is that, you should read the input outside the `while` loop where you are doing the processing with the input. That is the 2nd thing you didn't followed.

Currently your while loop is: -

```
    while (i>0) // while greater than 0
    {
        int input = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println (i%2);
        i = (i/2);
    }
```

This is read `input` from user on every iteration which you don't want.

So, you need to modify your code a little bit: -

```
int i = scan.nextInt();  // Read input outside the while loop

while (i>0) // while greater than 0
{      
    System.out.println (i%2);
    i = i/2;   // You don't need a bracket here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
```

Comment: @Bohemian.. This thing OP can use to show to his Teacher. No guarantee that he don't get punished for not following the pseudo code. lol ;)

Comment: @RohitJain I know what you mean, however I think learning the API *is* learning the language. No one in real life would use anything else than this code. I wish teachers would set exercises that are "reasonable" problems that do not have an "API" solution. Oh, and I +! your answer :)

Comment: @Bohemian.. Yeah you are right, that knowing the API is important. But I guess in the beginning, one should avoid using them, so as to learn the basics.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo code reads first (outside the loop), but in your code you read second (inside the loop)